# Calling public method of user control from a parent form

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, user-controls

I have form containing a Clear Button, usercontrol. The userControl has some text box and labels.

On the click of clear button the entries in the textbox should get cleared.

I have written a public method in userControl class which clears entries on from text box.

How to call this `clear()` method from clicking clear button from parent form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `Clear()` method should be something like this

```
//this method in the userControl
public void Clear()
{
   //Clear your text box
   this.txtbox1.Text = string.Empty;
   //Do other clean-up things if you want
}
```

now in your parent form, use your userControl name (you must add the userControl to your parent form) and call this code upon clicking the button event

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Call the Clear method from the UserControl
   yourUserControlName.Clear();
}
```

otherwise, please share your code.

Comment: This is what exactly my code does.But the changes does not get reflected on the main form.The Main form still contains the old values on the text box.

Comment: try to call `this.Refresh()` after the `Clear()` method, plus you can add `this.Refresh()` to the `Clear()` method it self

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the `UserControl` from the parent form, which you should have anyway, there should not be any problem calling that Public function. I am not sure how you have designed your code, but you should be able to call Public functions on Child Controls as needed.

The reverse would be bit complicated though, for which you would need to use delegates.

Comment: The public method is getting called but the changes does happen on the main form

Comment: @NIleshLanke: Isn't the public function implemented to Clear the UserControl TextBox? Not sure why it happens to the main form..

Answer (score 0):

if it is as easy as it sounds:

add an action on your button and the button1_click will appear

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        YourForm();
    }
```